# Why is this definition $F_{*}$ between tangent space is indepedent of the germ?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am currently reading Tu differential manifolds. I proved that $F_{*}(X_p)$ is a derivation at $F(p)$ but I don't understand why is it independent of the germ used ? [image]

Answer (score 0):

Two germs agree on a nbd of $p$, and $X$ is a derivative so the result depends only on the germ.